# How to continue execution if error occurs for an element in application?

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver

I have a task to create clients using one application using selenium webdriver. i am not using any framework. i have automated the complete application and i am creating the clients by reading and riting data to excel.

Actual Problem:

if take existing client name(1st row in excel), am getting error in application while automating and execution is interrupted. i want to continue the execution for 2nd row in excel even if i get the error for 1st row in excel.

code is like:

```
for (i = 1; i <= ExcelUtils.GetNoofRows; i++) {
    // code for elements 
    // here i have one element for clientname field where i am getting error 
    // as client already exists
}
```

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Show us your code and the error message, please.

Comment: i cant provide the code as it is designed in client system. error message is 'Client Already Exists'

Comment: Then check for existence somehow and don't do anything if the client already exists. Sorry, but without having a look at the code, it will be impossible to provide proper help. What about the error message? Can you provide that?

Comment: Error message is appearing for the element: "the clientname you have provided is already exists. please provide another cientname"

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is this, though I wouldn't recommend this practice:

[I wrote this referencing the wrong language. Skip to notes below. Apologies.]

Surround your code with `On Error Resume Next` and then `On Error Goto 0`. This will tell VBA not to stop on an error, but instead to continue to the next line.

This might get you going in the short term. A better solution would be to create an error handler, note the error row somewhere if you want, and the resume your loop with a Resume statement at the bottom of the loop. Read up on VBA error handling.

[Edit due to the comment below pointing out I'd been an idiot. My words.] Most of the above is correct other than the language. Read up on Try/Catch.

Comment: Where in this question have you read about VBA? I think it's about Java (see the tags) and apache poi (that's an educated guess).

Comment: You're completely right. I saw it as an Excel problem and didn't focus closely enough on the code. Sorry Praveen. The solution is the same, it just has different syntax. Read up on Try/Catch in Java. You'll see how convenient it is. Much neater than VBA error handling.